# Cпарсить C-подобный формат на python

Tags: python, парсер

Нужно сделать парсер вот такого формата, как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо!

```
"Users"
{
    "STEAM_0:0:15256262"
    {
        "name"   "polly"
        "expires"   "0"
        "flags"   "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"
    }
    "STEAM_0:1:24536789"
    {
        "name"   "test_user"
        "expires"   "0"
        "flags"   "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"
    }

}
```

Нужно, чтобы на выходе парсер выдавал что-то типо:

```
[{"steam_id": "STEAM_0:0:15256262", "name": "polly", "expires": "0", "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"},
 {"steam_id": "STEAM_0:1:24536789", "name": "test_user", "expires": "0", "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"}]
```

Comment: Выглядит как поломанный json

Comment: Первый блок это что? Ты что хочешь спарсить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накидал простенький парсер:

- Перебираем построчно и считаем количество открывающих и закрывающих скобок
- Заполняем данные в зависимости от текущего уровня вложенности

  - Для первого уровня, т.е. `steam_id` достаточно вернуть строку без первого и последнего символа
  - Для вытаскивания ключ-значений типа `name` используется регулярное выражение `"(.+?)"\s+"(.+?)"`, которое означает поиск в строке пары кавычек с текстом внутри (`"(.+?)"`), разделенными пробелами (`\s+`)

Пример:

```
import re


text = """\
"Users"
{
    "STEAM_0:0:15256262"
    {
        "name"   "polly"
        "expires"   "0"
        "flags"   "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"
    }
    "STEAM_0:1:24536789"
    {
        "name"   "test_user"
        "expires"   "0"
        "flags"   "0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z"
    }
}
"""

items = []
current_level = 0

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line == '{':
        current_level += 1
        continue
    elif line == '}':
        current_level -= 1
        continue

    if current_level == 1:
        steam_id = line[1:-1]
        items.append({'steam_id': steam_id})

    elif current_level == 2:
        m = re.search(r'"(.+?)"\s+"(.+?)"', line)
        key, value = m.group(1), m.group(2)
        items[-1][key] = value

print(items)
```

Результат:

```
[{'steam_id': 'STEAM_0:0:15256262', 'name': 'polly', 'expires': '0', 'flags': '0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z'}, {'steam_id': 'STEAM_0:1:24536789', 'name': 'test_user', 'expires': '0', 'flags': '0a0b0c0d0h0n0p0t0w0x1b1e1f1h1k1n0z'}]
```

---

**PS.**

Если считывать из файла, то есть такие варианты:

1. Считать в переменную:

   ```
   with open('путь до файла', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       text = f.read()
       ...
   ```
2. Считывать из файла построчно:

   ```
   with open('путь до файла', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       items = []
       current_level = 0

       for line in f:
           ...
   ```

Второй вариант особенно подходит, когда файл не влезет в память

Comment: Тоже вариант, я примерно также хотел сделать, но он вроде как должен файл парсить, так, что надо прогу переделать чутка.

Comment: @Just_a_programmer, ну да :) Добавил в ответ варианты с файлом

Comment: Ну теперь вроде всё ок)))

Answer (score -1):

Если первый блок это файл, информацию из которого ты хочешь спарсить, то открой файл и в строковую переменную запиши спарсенный текст.
`file = open('путь к файлу', 'r')`
`txt = file.read()` 
Дальше есть строковые методы, ищешь ключевые фразы, например:

> "name"

и смотришь на слова после них.